# Excel 2010: Formulas not showing correct answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'll try and explain this as best as I can, it's a strange one so please bear with me. For the record I am using Excel 2010 (although I have seen this a couple of times before on previous versions also), and the model is fairly large (~30MB) containing around 20 sheets, and around 15 modules (although very well optimised and calculation times are non-existent).

I don't have the exact figures to hand, but for example in cells A1:A3 I have the values 823.50, -350.00, and -497.50 respectively. In cell B2, I am simply adding the values in column A by using =A1+A2+A3.

One would expect the result to show -24.00, but in fact shows something along the lines of 548.50.

- Calculations are set to automatic
- Application.ScreenUpdating = True
- Formatting is set to General
- Manually stepping through the 'evaluate formula' dialog returns the correct result right up until the last step, which then gives the incorrect result

This can be fixed manually by entering into the cell, and coming back out again (effectively F2 then enter), after which the cell shows the correct result.

It is definitely not just a visual error, as the incorrect result gets fed into other calculations. I know the quick fix is to F2 and enter each cell, but it was only by chance this morning that the error was spotted, and could have easily resulted in a very large, false cost.

**Edit**

*Forgot to mention that this affected ~50 cells this morning, not just the one*

Has anyone had any experience with this issue? Is it a known issue, and therefore a known solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do A1:A3 have static values or rely on formulas / custom VBA functions?

Comment: They rely on several cells spread across the sheets. Some are static, others are calculated. There are no custom functions in the model

Comment: send us a dummy example file so we can have a closer look at the file.

Comment: I might take this to [Microsoft Help](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us?auth=1), where you should be able to send your file in, get confirmation that it is, in fact a bug, and get suggestions for workarounds if it's not.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't send a dummy file as it's not something I can replicate outside of the model. I have seen the same issue before (not just in this model, but in other files too), but have never pinned down the answer. And thank you for the suggestion, but I wouldn't be able to send the file in due to confidentiality issues.

Answer (score 0):

The only things I've noticed was to use '=Sum' instead of just '=', but have never been sure it actually functions differently.

also, from MS: If an argument is a cell range or reference, only numeric values in the reference or range can be added

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this isn't the issue.